# Jars required for REST web services

Tags: java, rest, jersey

My project requires Java 1.6 and JRE 6. Initially I developed Rest WS using Jersey 2.7 and it was working successfully. When we deployed the project in production, errors were pouring in. This is because, production environment is using JDK 1.6 and JRE 6. Now am using the below code in web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>com.model</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Can anyone pls let me know the list of jars used for restful WS which are compatible with JDK 6 and JRE 6?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Umm... So you have no JDK where you'r server is standing? Or no JDK where you develop? Are you sure you diagnosed the errors correctly?

Comment: For the future, it is just "Java 6". There is no difference between JDK 6 or JRE 6 regarding compatibility, its one and the same compatibility version of Java.

Answer (score 2):

try [Jersey 2.6](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html).

> Until version 2.6, Jersey was compiled with Java SE 6. This has
>   changes in Jersey 2.7